# Rsync --files-from not placing in the destination directory

Tags: macos, terminal, rsync

In the OS X terminal I am using the follow `rsync` command to transfer some source folders to the destination.

```
rsync -vrl --files-from=/Users/myname/Desktop/myFiles.txt / /Users/Mynames/Desktop/DestFolder
```

And these are the files that are being transferred (listed in myFiles.txt):

```
/users/myname/Downloads/downloaded-files1
/users/myname/Downloads/downloaded-files2
/users/myname/Downloads/downloaded-files3
```

*The copy process is completed without errors.*

The problem is on destination folder I get full paths like bellow.

```
    /users/myname/Downloads/downloaded-files1
    /users/myname/Downloads/downloaded-files2
    etc..
```

I want only the last part **/downloaded-files1**.

What options should be passed to place the files in the destination directory that is specified on the commandline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you just want the files, with any directory structure flattened, then you can simply add the `--no-relative` option to your command.

---

*If* you want to preserve any directory structure, then you need to form your command like this:

```
rsync -vrl --files-from=/Users/myname/Desktop/myFiles.txt /users/myname/Downloads/ /Users/Mynames/Desktop/DestFolder
```

And use this as your list:

```
downloaded-files1
downloaded-files2
downloaded-files3
```

Rsync uses the source directory for the "root" of the files copied.